# If an element of a basis is a scalar multiple of an element of another basis, are the two bases considered distinct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have the bases {(1,0) (0,1)} and {(1,0) (0,-1)}

We see that (0,-1) is a scalar multiple of (0,1). Are the two bases considered distinct?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, and even interchanging the two vectors is considered (for most purposes, notably for expressing arbitrary vectors in the basis) to give a different basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vectors in the two bases are distinct and will have **different** linear combinations to represent the **same vectors**.

So yes, the 2 bases **are distinct**.
However we only use one basis for a vector space and {(1,0),(0,1)} is more conventional.

Comment: So as long as the coordinates for a given vector are different for two bases, the two bases are considered distinct? Thank you.

Comment: @user64742 Not "for a given vector", but for **some** vectors. There may be vectors (apart from the zero vector) with the same coordinates in both bases (any $(x,0)$ in your example), but this will not make the two bases equal.